# Azure DevOps Release - Ruby script: everything is cut after & in a secret variable

Tags: ruby, variables, azure-devops

It seems like my problem is very close to the one described [here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/498097/azure-devops-variable-secret-password-with-special.html)

I have `Azure DevOps` release definition with the predefined secret variable (not secret in the screenshot below to better illustrate the problem)

[image: Azure DevOps variable]

In the release definition there is Ruby script that reads this variable, but for some strange reason only Smith is taken and everything after that is cut, hence my release keeps failing

**Ruby script example**
[image]

**Azure DevOps Log example**
[image]

My biggest suspicion is this is something to do with ampersand special character `&`

Has anyone else faced similar situation before?

*Updating question due to most recent comments*

I don't pass passwords in clear text. Here, it is done as an example. I always pass it as secret variable
[image]

Then this secret variable is passed to the script as an argument
[image]

What I've tried so far

1. This [image] leads to this
   [image]

---

2. This [image] leads to this [image]

   ---
3. This [image] leads to this [image]

---

Comment: How do you pass the variable to the program?

Comment: Maybe you need to escape this somehow, like `&amp;`, or you're receiving it via a URL and you forgot to escape it there.

Comment: **WARNING**: Can't not mention that logging plain-text passwords is a [**spectacularly bad idea**](https://www.adweek.com/digital/twitter-corrected-a-bug-that-caused-passwords-to-be-stored-in-plain-text/).

Comment: Look like the second option that you tried it's the most close, maybe after you get the password try to remove the `" "` from the string.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a ruby script here, but I use powershell to pass variable with the & symbol to a ps1 script, get an error, and prompt according to the error message: the ampersand (&) character is not allowed. The & operator is reserved for future use. You can try to wrap an ampersand in double quotation marks ("&") to pass it as part of a string. Hope this helps.